# Proxying Firebase api-calls in an Angular application

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

We are developing an application based on firebase and angular. Now we have some potential clients who need to explicitly whitelist all connections in their firewall, but don't want to allow generic google domains.
Because we are using the angularfire2 library account-related requests are send to www.googleapis.com and other database related requests to firestore.googleapis.com.

Our idea to solve this problem is to proxy this api calls with nginx through one of our subdomains (like apix.domain.com instead of firestore.googleapis.com) such that the customers can allow communication in their firewall with this host (apix.domain.com).

Is it possible to configure this URLs in angularfire2? If this is impossible, does anyone have another approach to solve the issue?